# How to increase compare speed between two array?

Tags: java, performance

i have two integer array, each size 95700.i want compare to two integer arrays,i got maximum size of integer using Integer.MAX_VALUE(2147483647).

i used following code,

```
for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++) {
    if (array1[i] == 0xFF0000FF && array2[i] == 0xFFFFFFFF) {
        matched++;              
    } else {
        unMatched++;
    }
}
```

this code taking lot of time(50s). How to decreases comparison time...please help me

EDIT:
this is my logcat:

```
12-22 15:20:29.638: INFO/System.out(1660): start time-----18041173568804 
12-22 15:20:29.638: INFO/System.out(1660): time-----40981116222 
12-22 15:20:29.688: INFO/System.out(1660): The array comparison toook an average of 40.981116 second
```

Comment: If you just want to know when the two arrays are "different", you could `break` in the `else` branch.

Comment: 50s to compare two arrays of 96K elements sounds highly implausible. Could you produce a self-contained example that we could play with?

Comment: you could start with changing array1.length to '95700'.

Comment: i want find how many matched in two arrays

Comment: What do you mean "compare"? Do you want to check if they have different contents? It seems you want to know if *every* element is a fixed value. Also, note that you loop may be split into two separate loops because you never test array1 against array2

Comment: It is hard to imagine how it could be taking 50 seconds.  It is also hard to imagine how `array1[i] == 0xFF0000FF && array2[i] == 0xFFFFFFFF` would be considered a match.  There must be a lot going on you are not telling us about.  Can you explain why its taking 50 seconds?

Comment: each array size 95700,i think that's

Comment: I just timed a loop like yours (testing every element and incrementing) over an array of size 95700, and it took 2 milliseconds (running on an old macbook pro). You're not telling us the whole story!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide more detail because there is no way the array comparison is taking 50 seconds, or even 50 milli-seconds as described

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] array1 = new int[95700];
    int[] array2 = new int[95700];
    for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; j += 3) {
        array1[j] = 0xFF0000FF;
        array2[j] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int runs = 10000;
    int matched = 0, unMatched = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < runs; r++) {
        matched = unMatched = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            if (array1[i] == 0xFF0000FF && array2[i] == 0xFFFFFFFF) {
                matched++;
            } else {
                unMatched++;
            }
        }
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("The array comparison to an average of %.6f second, matched=%,d, unmatched=%,d%n",
            time / 1e9 / runs, matched, unMatched);
}
```

prints

```
The array comparison to an average of 0.000109 second, matched=31,900, unmatched=63,800
```

That is one tenth of one milli-second.

Comment: this is my logcat 12-22 15:20:29.638: INFO/System.out(1660): start time-----18041173568804

12-22 15:20:29.638: INFO/System.out(1660): time-----40981116222

12-22 15:20:29.688: INFO/System.out(1660): The array comparison toook an average of 40.981116 second

Comment: in ur case first comparison always false, so no need to compare second one that's y u got 0.000109. in my case first comparison may be true or false.

Comment: Between `12-22 15:20:29.638` and `12-22 15:20:29.688` is 50 milli-seconds.

Comment: Changed the example so it matches 1/3 of the time.

Comment: just tell me in ur case first comparison always false, so no need to compare second one right

Comment: `just i used sys after loop` What do you mean?

Comment: @Chiru I have change the code so it matches sometimes. It made no difference to the timing.

Answer (score 1):

On which platform/system is that running?

How are the variables declared?
`Integer` instead of `int` would cause some delay, but still not enough to get 50 seconds.

I tested that code snippet on my very old laptop (debugger, client mode) and it took less than 1 millisecond.

There is one optimization you can try, but don't expect much:

```
for (int i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] == 0xFF0000FF && array2[i] == 0xFFFFFFFF) {
        matched++;
    }
}
unMatched = array1.length - matched;
```

Comment: in ur case first comparison always false, so no need to compare second one . in my case first comparison may be true or false.

Comment: @Chiru - WHY? It is exactly the same as yours, I just removed the else block (since the value of `unMatched` can be calculated). And for sure I added some data to the arrays so both checks may be needed...